# Finds the number of times each word occurs and save in php array

Tags: php, arrays, string

i want create a function countWords($str) that takes any string of characters and finds the number of times each word occurs. exp:

"hello world"

**character**  || **number of times ouccr**

```
h                   1
e                   1
l                   3
o                   2
w                   1
r                   1
d                   1
```

help me !!

Thanks....

Comment: Look up explode and associative arrays at http://php.net

Comment: you might want to look into str_split function: http://us.php.net/str_split

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$str = 'hello world';
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
$arr = str_split($str);

$rep = array_count_values($arr);

foreach ($rep as $key => $value) {

echo $key . "  =  " . $value . '<br>';

}
```

Output:

```
h = 1
e = 1
l = 3
o = 2
w = 1
r = 1
d = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way counts any matches and returns the number

```
<?php

function counttimes($word,$string){

    //look for the matching word ignoring the case.
    preg_match_all("/$word/i", $string, $matches);  

    //count all inner array items - 1 to ignore the initial array index
    return count($matches, COUNT_RECURSIVE) -1;     
}

$string = 'Hello World, hello there Hello World';
$word = 'h';

//call the function
echo counttimes($word,$string);

?>
```